# Anyone know how to upload files into a Sharepoint Library using javascript and the SOAP API in SP 2010?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, soap, file

I am writing custom forms in javascript.

I do not have access to visual studio. I need to be able to upload a file into a document library with meta data.

I've been playing around with the Copy.asmx and the CopyToItems method, but I keep getting a 400 bad request error.

any help would be appreciated...

Kris

Comment: Can i get the source code for this. Looking out for this since a month.

Comment: i can give you some sample code on how to do this using Client Object Model if you want ?

Comment: @SebastienStettler Sure, I would love some code to do this with the COM.

Comment: @Jeetu Unfortunately, I'm not able to share code as I'm doing this for my company. But, I will say that it comes out looking very hackish by just using the Upload.aspx page.

I now have the go ahead to use Visual Studio and C#, so I can write my own uploader.

Keep on the look out for Sebastien's COM code solution. That may be a much better solution than using the OOTB Upload.aspx page.

Comment: cool will add a answer as soon as i can free up some time. is it possible for me to drop the C# COM code and then you port it to JS ? only the syntax should change the methods etc will stay the same

Answer (score 2):

You can't use only JavaScript to do this.

The [CopyIntoItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method takes a `byte[] stream` parameter. This means you need to be able to read a file into a byte array *and then* pass this to the method. This first step isn't possible in JavaScript.

Comment: I've settled on a solution which involves IFRAMES and JQuery.

This allows me to use SP's Upload.aspx page directly. I have used javascript in order to feed it the correct list ID.

thanks for your help

Comment: Ah very cool! The Upload.aspx was the missing piece. :)

Comment: @KristopherBlair care to share the solution you used?

Comment: Would anyone mind actually answering the question here so that other people can use your solution?